# How to escape html entities in C?

Tags: html, c, string, escaping, entities

I'm trying to decode HTML entities (in the format `&#39;`) in C.

So far I've got some code to try and decode them but it seems to produce odd output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* convertHtmlEntities(char* str) {
    size_t length = strlen(str);
    size_t i;
    char *endchar = malloc(sizeof(char));
    long charCode;
    if (!endchar) {
        fprintf(stderr,"not enough memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
        if (*(str+i) == '&' && *(str+i+1) == '#' && *(str+i+2) >= '0' && *(str+i+2) <= '9' && *(str+i+3) >= '0' && *(str+i+3) <= '9' && *(str+i+4) == ';') {
            charCode = strtol(str+i+2,&endchar,0);
            printf("ascii %li\n",charCode);
            *(str+i) = charCode;
            strncpy(str+i+1,str+i+5,length - (i+5));
            *(str + length - 5) = 0; /* null terminate string */
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char string[] = "Helloworld&#39;s parent company has changed - comF";
    printf("%s",convertHtmlEntities(&string));
}
```

I'm not sure if the main statement is correct because I just made it for this example as my program generates it from a web url, however the idea is the same.

The function does replace the `&#39;` with a apostrophe, but the output is garbled at the end and just after the replacement.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I think it is because you are replacing 5 characters with 1 character, you are moving the trailing characters to their correct places, but you need to shorten the string by the number of characters you have removed. (removing those at the end)

Comment: I'd expect that - but that's not what's happening.. 
e.g. "Helloworld&#39;s parent company has changed - comF" becomes "Helloworld's parcompanypany has changed - comF"
???

Comment: In main `&string` is a `char**`; the convertHtmlEntities() function expects a `char*`. You shouldn't use the `&`: `printf("%s", convertHtmlEntities(string));` is ok.

Comment: BTW, you don't have to malloc memory for `endchar` since `strtol` will update the pointer to point inside the string passed in first parameter. You just have to do `char* endchar = NULL; long charCode = strtol(str+i+2,&endchar,0);`, otherwise you are leaking memory.

Comment: @Adam, @Sylvain: and as `endchar` is not used it might as well not be declared at all and use `NULL` in strtol: `strtol(str+i+2, NULL, 10)`

Comment: @Sylvain, @pmg:  I must have forgot to put *endchar = ';';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strncpy` (or `strcpy`) does not work for overlapping strings.

Your strings `str+i+1` and `str+i+5` overlap. Don't do that!

Replace `strncpy` with `memmove`

```
            *(str+i) = charCode;
            memmove(str+i+1,str+i+5,length - (i+5) + 1); /* also copy the '\0' */
            /* strncpy(str+i+1,str+i+5,length - (i+5)); */
            /* *(str + length - 5) = 0; */ /* null terminate string */
```

Answer (score 0):

I had another problem with the code - it cut the last 'F' character. I replaced this line:

```
 *(str + length - 5) = 0; /* null terminate string */
```

with this:

```
 *(str + length - 4) = 0; /* null terminate string */
```

I belive it's because you delete five chars and add one, so the new length is not old-5, but old-4.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to those small details; I assumed you had them right :)